# Python face recognition

Tags: python, face-recognition

Hey guys lately I was working on attendance system with face recognition and I am using face-recognition library in order to do that I need to encode the images so I used for loop to iterate over the images and encode them but I am getting error that says

```
encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I even saw on yt people doing this and it worked perfectly fine but it's not working for me.I am using python 3.7.6
here is the full code:

```
import cv2
import face_recognition
import pickle
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import storage

cred = credentials.Certificate("Service acc key data base.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': "Don't mind this",
    'storageBucket': "Don't mind this"
})

# Importing student images
folderPath = 'Images'
pathList = os.listdir(folderPath)
print(pathList)
imgList = []
studentIds = []
for path in pathList:
    imgList.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(folderPath, path)))
    studentIds.append(os.path.splitext(path)[0])

    fileName = f'{folderPath}/{path}'
    bucket = storage.bucket()
    blob = bucket.blob(fileName)
    blob.upload_from_filename(fileName)

    # print(path)
    # print(os.path.splitext(path)[0])
print(studentIds)

def findEncodings(imagesList):
    encodeList = []
    for img in imagesList:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList


print("Encoding Started ...")
encodeListKnown = findEncodings(imgList)
print(encodeListKnown)
encodeListKnownWithIds = [encodeListKnown, studentIds]
print("Encoding Complete")

file = open("EncodeFile.p", 'wb')
pickle.dump(encodeListKnownWithIds, file)
file.close()
print("File Saved")
```

I have tried everything that i know

Comment: @AliEnt Sorry, I don't understand can u make it clear pls?

Comment: Sorry I forgot there is `cv2.cvtColor` there. So you are reading images correctly and I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

When `face_recognition.face_encodings(img)` doesn't find any face it returns an empty list `[]` so `[0]` gives you Index Error. you must first check if face exists in image.

```py
encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)
if len(encodings) > 0:

    # Append encode to encodList
    encodeList.append(encode)

locations = face_recognition.face_locations(img)
if len(locations) == 0:
    # no images found
    continue
```

for more info you can check [list index out of range error in facial recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452362/list-index-out-of-range-error-in-facial-recognition)

Comment: tnks but I have a question does it choose images it works on some of the image and doesn't work on some of them why?

Comment: maybe the position of face in the image is not good enough to detect it. you can chose which model to use for face detection.